# How to find details about Negative Reputation

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation is down to 750 from 760 in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I can't find any negative reputation in reputation history. Why this happened? How to find the details about the negative reputation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your reputation page (in your profile), check the box that says "Show Removed Posts".

Looking at your profile, there appears to be no downvotes, nor the 'User was Removed' deduction. It is probably a case of an answer was deleted, or several edited posts.

Comment: damn. you're right..Thanks!!!

Comment: you're most welcome!